# How to check if Mouse Pointer is visible?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way within C#.Net to check if the mouse pointer is visible?
(As it is on Touch devices for example)

Or the symbol type of it? 
(Pointer, Loading-circle, hidden)

Comment: WPF, WinForm, Silverlight/Store, HTML, which?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at using [Cursor.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.current%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> A Cursor that represents the mouse cursor. **The default is null if
>   the mouse cursor is not visible.**

So something like

```
Cursor current = Cursor.Current;

if(current == null)
    //the cursor is not visible
else
    //the cursor is visible
```

Comment: On Windows 10, I found that Cursor.Current never returned null even after calling Cursor.Hide. Ingmar's answer worked better for me.

Answer (score 4):

I found empirically that **Cursor.Current == null** does **not** indicate the cursor hidden status (Windows 10 Pro, .Net 4.7, Windows.Forms, 2020.04.07).

To clarify the problem, I want to check (not set) the cursor hidden status because that seems to be the only way to detect reliably if a mouse event was raised by mouse/touchpad (cursor is visible) or by finger touch (cursor not visible).

Diving into Win32 calls allows to check this state successfully:

```
#region Cursor info

public static class CursorExtensions {

  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
  struct PointStruct {
    public Int32 x;
    public Int32 y;
  }

  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
  struct CursorInfoStruct {
    /// <summary> The structure size in bytes that must be set via calling Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(CursorInfoStruct)).</summary>
    public Int32 cbSize;
    /// <summary> The cursor state: 0 == hidden, 1 == showing, 2 == suppressed (is supposed to be when finger touch is used, but in practice finger touch results in 0, not 2)</summary>
    public Int32 flags;
    /// <summary> A handle to the cursor. </summary>
    public IntPtr hCursor; 
    /// <summary> The cursor screen coordinates.</summary>
    public PointStruct pt; 
  }

  /// <summary> Must initialize cbSize</summary>
  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  static extern bool GetCursorInfo(ref CursorInfoStruct pci);

  public static bool IsVisible(this Cursor cursor) {
    CursorInfoStruct pci = new CursorInfoStruct();
    pci.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(CursorInfoStruct));
    GetCursorInfo(ref pci);
    // const Int32 hidden = 0x00;
    const Int32 showing = 0x01;
    // const Int32 suppressed = 0x02;
    bool isVisible = ((pci.flags & showing) != 0);
    return isVisible;
  }

}

#endregion Cursor info
```

The client code is now quite convenient:

```
bool isTouch = !Cursor.Current.IsVisible();
```

Comment: This worked for me, but it only reflected the Cursor.Hide / Cursor.Show state when the cursor was over my own app's window.

Answer (score 2):

[According to MSDN :](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.current%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Property Value
>   Type: System.Windows.Forms.Cursor
>   A Cursor that represents the mouse cursor. The default is null if the mouse cursor is not visible.

So this code should do the job :

```
If (Cursor.Current == null)
{
    // cursor is invisible
}
else
{
    // cursor is visible
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `System.Windows.Forms.Cursor` class to get the info;

Using `Cursor.Current` property!

```
if (Cursor.Current == null)
{
    //
}
```

Comment: A "wait" cursor is *visible*.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about a WPF variant, then the Cursor property of a framework element should be `None` if it's not visible.